# No puedo ejecutar la pagina de inicio Django

Tags: django

Estoy tratando de aplicar mi pagina de inicio con contraseña, pero me dice que la orden no funciona, y he podido encontrar por que. este es el error que me muestra, al ejecutar:

[image: imagen de error]

mis urls del propyecto:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("empleado/", include("apps.empleado.urls")),
    path("liquida/", include("apps.liquida.urls")),
    path("usuario/", include("apps.usuario.urls")),
    path("login/", views.LoginView.as_view(),{'template_name':'index.html'}),
]
```

esta es mi template para el login:

```
% extends 'base/base.html' %}

{% block title %}

{% endblock %}
{% block navbar%}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<br>
<h1>Iniciar sesión - Login</h1>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Nombre de usuario:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username">
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Contraseña:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password">
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <a href="#">Olvidé mi contraseña</a>
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Ingresar">
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Mi settings:

```
#LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('empleado:empleado_listar')
```

Cuelaquier ayuda lo agradeceria, no logro poder aplicar el login, no me genera la plantilla de inicio y contraseña.

Comment: No hay una URL raiz o root ("/" o ""), es decir una de pagina de inicio. Si quieres que el inicio de tu pagina sea el "login", cambia la ruta de la URL del login: `"login/"` por `""`.

Comment: TemplateDoesNotExist at /
registration/login.html, hice el cambio pero ahora me sale este error.

Comment: El error es claro, el template `registration/login.html`, **no existe**, creo que cambiaste el nombre del template, debes cambiar la ruta de la URL login, en tu archivo `urls.py`.

Comment: Gracias amigo, esto soluciono mi problema, path("", views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name='index'), tuve en cuenta tu recomendacion, justo lo que buscaba.

Comment: Eso te dije que hagas desde un principio xd, Saludos! :)

Answer (score 0):

En el `urlpatterns` tienes q agregar una `path` para cuando es la raiz del sitio. Algo como esto:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path("", views.HomePageView.as_view(),{'template_name':'index.html'}),
    # ...
]
```

o simplemente cambiar el `path` del login a la raiz del sitio.

Comment: es correcto justo me faltaba ese path, para redireccionar el inicio. garcias